# Bitmap hittesting in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript, bitmap, hittest

I'm building a 16 bit game for my final project and have completed all the objects and environments, I exported all the images as png files into flash as well as my character, breaking the environment up into background, objects and foreground. I can't however find a simple tutorial explaining how to do bitmap hit testing or another simple way of making my character not be able to move into the objects.

Could someone recommend a simple tutorial or an alternative method of achieving this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this great tutorial about using `BitmapData.hitTest` for collision detection:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

Also, if you are building a flash game I think you should look into using a **Flash Game Engine**, for example for 2D games, plataformers and such I'd recommend:

- [FlashPunk](http://flashpunk.net/)
- or [Flixel](http://flixel.org/)

Both will help you A LOT with game development specific stuff such as collision detection, user input, etc which should speed up your workflow. Hope this helps!