# hitTestObject not working properly AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

How to make the objects detect each other without having to be so accurate? Currently, the program that I'm working on only allow the items to be matched when it is accurately matched at the upper left edge but i did not use hitTestPoint, I used hitTestObject. Below are my codes.

```
if (bin1.hitTestObject(item)){ 
        updateShape(item, bin1);
```

Comment: what do you mean "without having to be so accurate?"

Comment: because it can only detect the other object when it hit the upper left edge, it cannot detect when it is drag to anywhere else.

Comment: Try looking into `BitmapData.hitTest`, which is what it sounds like you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitmap hittesting in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046930/bitmap-hittesting-in-as3)

Answer (score 1):

If `bin1` and `item` are both DisplayObjects, which I don't see how they couldn't be (DisplayObject is a base class that's extended by a bunch of others like MovieClip and Sprite) then you should be able to just do a little quick and dirty calculation yourself. The way you worded your question led me to believe that `bin1` and `item` have their origins in the top left, so you should be able to use this code to see if the complete rectangles that both of them inhabit are hitting, which isn't all that accurate if the objects are rotated, but it sounds like that's almost what you're looking for:

```
if(Math.abs((bin1.x+bin1.width/2)-(item.x+item.width.2)) < bin1.width/2 + item.width/2 &&
   Math.abs((bin1.y+bin1.height/2)-(item.y+item.height/2)) < bin1.height/2 + item.height/2)
      updateShape(item,bin1);
```

If their origins aren't actually in the top left and are centered, remove all the `.width/2` and `.height/2` parts with the `.x` and `.y` parts in the parentheses. Hopefully this helps!